# What does "double quotes" mean in chrome ? (This is weird)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I've noticed that Google Chrome wraps inner text of elements in **double quotes**, however, the Html() Jquery function returns a string without quotes . Why is that ?

And here are some experiments :

**Html Code :**

```
<p id="simple-text">This is a simple paragraph .</p>

<p id="lorem-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p id="span-text">This is a simple <span>span element</span> paragraph .</p>
```

**Result in Chrome ( Elements ):**

[image: Elements]

**Note: There are no double quotes in the simple text (#simple-text)**

**Result in Chrome using Jquery ( Console ):**

[image: Jquery]

**Note: There are no double quotes in the span text (#span-text)**

**Update (Editing Html) :**

[image]

[image]

**Could I say that there are three elements : string, span, and a string ?**

Comment: In that last picture, all of the inner HTML is undefined because `innerHtml` isn't actually a property, it should be `innerHTML`

Comment: @Sidney : Thanks man

Comment: The Chrome console pretty much does whatever the developers want it to do. It's trying to be helpful but there are *lots* of similar questions about how the console presents information.

Answer (score 9):

The quotes aren't actually a part of the DOM, it's just a UX feature in DevTools to indicate it's a string you're looking at.

[image]

If you right click the element and select `Edit HTML`, you'll see the raw HTML.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, (these quotes made me crazy) that makes sense now .

Comment: So in the span-text , there are three elements : string, span, and a string? right ?

Comment: "TextNode" would be better than "string" here.