# React: Why HTML content is displayed with double quotes in Dev Tool (Elements)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I'm build blog with Next.JS.

Why is HTML content displayed in double quotes in Chrome Dev Tools (Elements), when I pass text as children:

```
<h1>hello world tes {props.title}</h1>
```

Result:

[image]

And if I write the content inside dangerousSetInnerHTML, no double quotes:

```
<h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `hello world tes ${props.title}`}} />
```

Result:

[image]

**Which is the best practice, is it "children" or "dangerousSetInnerHTML"?**

Comment: Definitely use children and not `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. There's a reason the prop has that ridiculous name https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "double quotes" mean in chrome ? (This is weird)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390905/what-does-double-quotes-mean-in-chrome-this-is-weird)